# How can I find the source of a "module not found" crash after no user activity?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crash

I have written a couple of Windows forms vb.net apps that have recently started crashing intermittently with no error message; the forms just disappear from the screen. It seems to happen only when I haven't been doing anything in the user interface for several seconds, but it's not reproducible. It's not connected to a specific form. When it happens in debug mode, Visual Studio gives the message "The program '[27764] TimeSer.exe' has exited with code 3228369022 (0xc06d007e) 'Module not found'.".

I have set a global unhandled exception handler but it's not trapping the error. The event log says the faulting module name is KERNELBASE.dll and it gives a faulting process ID number that is not the same from one crash to the next, but I don't know how to use this information.

How can I figure out which module is not being found? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any timers perhaps on these forms?  Is it all projects, if you create a new winforms project does it do the same thing?

Comment: @Hursey, thanks for your response. There are some timers in the code but none of them should be running when the crashes are happening. But that's an interesting idea; I'll check. I've also just created a simple new project to see if it crashes too.

Comment: I've had similar problems in the past. Usually the KernalBase fault is a very generic error that could be about anything. I think I had a deadlock once that showed as a KernalBase error. The way I fix these hard crashes without errors is to capture a crash dump and analyze it with windbg.